# expander collapse automatically when using Virtualization in list box

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization

I have a Listbox control and I have an expander control in all the items so that user can expand each of the item. But when I expand few items and scroll it. some times the expander get collapse automatically.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Background="LightBlue"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonDataTemplate}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" 
            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}" />
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>

    </ListBox>
```

and resources have

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <Grid>
            <Expander >
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Expander.Header>
                <!--This will take time to be instancied-->
                <!--<local:TimeConsumingControl />-->
                <!--Rest of the data template-->
                <Border Margin="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" MinHeight="40" CornerRadius="3" Padding="3">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <!--<RowDefinition />-->
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name : " Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" - Age : " Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How can I prevent the items from collapsing. I still want to use Virtualization.